# Why does Ubuntu support so many file compression formats?

Tags: 16.04, file-format, archive, compression

I don't know if only Ubuntu or all Linux distributions support so many file compression formats. But, why are so many formats supported? Where in Windows, by default only `.zip` files are supported. On Ubuntu, there are many supported such as `7z`, `.bz2`, `.gz`, etc. Why is this?

[image: Screenshot of file compression formats (Ubuntu)]

Comment: It's not so much Ubuntu as the industry supports them. One guy wrote one compression algorithm another guy came along and said "I can write a better one" which he did.

Comment: Look at it this way, that's the freedom you enjoy with Ubuntu and linux in general. Every one has something to offer!

Comment: @George and WinEunuuchs2Unix. So, the reason for the many file compression formats is because many people wrote better and better ones?

Comment: Yes, if you study each of them you will see differences in how they each perform tasks...

Comment: What a pleasure it is in Linux to simply right-click the compressed file and select 'Extract Here'.  Nothing to research, nothing to download, it's just done.

Comment: @chili555 An exception is `.rar` files. Though you can just use the command line to install needed packages and  'Extract here' will work again.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix maybe you could write an answer... this question looks like it's going to get closed as POB but I am voting to leave open (if this makes anyone cross, ping me and tell me I'm wrong...)

Comment: @Zanna Your wish is my command :)

Answer (score 1):

Different parts of the system use different compression formats and archive formats:

gzip (compression):

```
$ file - < /initrd.img
/dev/stdin: gzip compressed data, last modified: Wed Feb 22 01:10:21 2017, from Unix
```

cpio (archive):

```
$ gunzip < /initrd.img | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

bzip2 (compression):

```
$ sudo cat /vmlinuz | file -
/dev/stdin: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 4.4.0-64-generic (buildd@lgw01-56) #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x6, Normal VGA
```

`ar` (archive): Debian packages are actually `ar` archives, themselves containing variously compressed archives:

```
$ ar t /var/cache/apt/archives/zlib1g-dev_1%3a1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
debian-binary
control.tar.gz
data.tar.xz
```

tar (archive): The `control.tar.gz` and `data.tar.xz` are, of course, `tar` archives, gzip-compressed and xz-compressed respectively.

The compression format behind xz is LZMA, which is also used by 7z, hence you get 7z creation for free (but not 7z reading).

Accordingly, Ubuntu comes with support for a bunch of compression formats (as do most distros), because they're all in common use.

---

Why are all of these in use?

## Hysterical Raisins.

(Historical reasons.)

Why should all of these components move to using something else, potentially breaking backwards compatibility and taking a hell of a headache, for what might be minimal benefits?

---

On a side note, Windows itself supports multiple archiving and compression formats:

- Zip (of course)
- LZX (compression)
- [Cabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_(file_format)) (archive)
- [MSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) (archive)

Comment: "minimal benefits" is typically a package or two and a decade or so kilobytes fewer per compression algorithm. These programs are *tiny* compared to most software on your system.

Comment: BTW Windows also supports compressed EXEs.

Answer (score 0):

Many files are already compressed in modern day systems when it comes to audio, images, videos and games. For data files however there are lots of options available. The reason being that over time people developed new algorithms for faster speed or better compression rates.

From ([Lifehacker.com - Whats the best way to compress a bunch of files](http://lifehacker.com/5772385/whats-the-best-way-to-compress-a-bunch-of-files)) there is a nice write-up:

- **Zip:** It won't compress your files down a ton, but it's super fast and you don't need to install any extra software. Great for Windows and Mac users.
- **Tar.gz:** Similar to zip, tar.gz files are pretty darn fast. It's the most universally available option for Linux users, and also compresses files to a slightly smaller size than zip. Great for Linux usess.
  Tar.
- **bzip2:** Another great option for Linux users; tar.bzip2 is a bit slower than tar.gz, but will compress files to a smaller size.
- **7z:** The archive format made popular by our favorite compression tool, 7-Zip. It's pretty slow, but it compresses files like nobody's business. This is the best format to use if you need a really, really small file. 7-Zip is only available for Windows, but you can get a command-line tool for Mac OS X and Linux, too. 7z is one of the only compression formats that can split files up into multiple archives and put them back together, too. This may seem counterintuitive, but it's useful if you're trying to send many large files over something like email, which limits the size of the files you send
- **RAR:** This format is comparable to 7z. 7z usually has better compression, with a few notable exceptions like mp3s in which case RAR compresses to smaller sizes. However, the only software that creates RAR files (WinRAR) is shareware, and Windows-only. You can uncompress RAR files on Mac and Linux, but not create them. RAR can also split up compressed archives into multiple parts.

Comment: some nice info here... but OP only asked why there are so many, so possibly you could elaborate on that point?

Comment: I had searched many times for "history of file compression" but couldn't find anything suitable. Articles tend to be extremely long and technical. I'm running out of time this morning but after work I'll have another look.